# Is a blowing up always surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Consider $A$ a commutative ring, and $I\leq A$ an ideal. Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $Z=\mathrm{Spec}(A/I)$.

Consider the blowing-up algebra
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Bl}_I(A):=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty I^i=A\oplus I\oplus I^2\oplus\cdots
\end{equation}
which is graded such that $I^i$ has degree $i$.

The affine blowing-up algebra is, for $a\in I$ of degree 1 in $\mathrm{Bl}_I(A)$, the homogeneous localisation
\begin{equation}
A\Big[\frac{I}{a}\Big]:=\Big(\mathrm{Bl}_I(A)\Big)_{(a)}. 
\end{equation}

The blowing-up is $\mathrm{Bl}_ZX:=\mathrm{Proj}\big(\mathrm{Bl}_I(A)\big)$ and it is covered by
\begin{equation}
\big(\mathrm{Bl}_ZX\big)_a:=\mathrm{Spec}\Big(A\Big[\frac{I}{a}\Big]\Big). 
\end{equation}
for $a\in I$ of degree 1 in $\mathrm{Bl}_I(A)$.

My questions are:

- Is every $\big(\mathrm{Bl}_ZX\big)_a\to X$ surjective, when $\big(\mathrm{Bl}_ZX\big)_a\ne\emptyset$?
- Is $\mathrm{Bl}_ZX\to X$ surjective when it is not empty?
- If not, what about the images can we say?

Best wishes.

Comment: If $X$ is a variety over a field $k$ it follows from Hartshorne, Prop.II.7.6  that $Bl_I(X) \rightarrow X$ is birational, proper and surjective.